# docker compose vs docker run - node container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to setup container for react app. My goal is to use `docker-compose` (I want to execute one command and have everything working)

The problem is that when I am trying you do it with docker-compose and docker file (which are below) I am getting information that:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
react:
    build: ./images/react
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - "/home/my/path:/app"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:6.9

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**Result**

> npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'

But when I did it with docker run and volumes mapping I was able to see packages.json and run npm install command.

```
docker run -it --rm -v /home/my/path:/app node:6.9 bash
```

Why it is not working with docker compose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the volume that you're describing in your `docker-compose.yml` file will be mounted at *run time*, not at *build time*. This means that when building the image, there will not be any `package.json` file there (yet), from which you could install your dependencies.

When `run`ning the container image with `-v /home/my/path:/app`, you're actually mounting the directory first, and subsequent `npm install` invocations will complete succesfully.

If you intend to mount your application (including `package.json`) into your container, the `npm install` needs to happen at run time (`CMD`), and not at build time (`RUN`).

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to simply add the `npm install` statement to your `CMD` instruction (and drop the `RUN npm install` instruction):

```
CMD npm install && npm start
```